# Add a new column combining two columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with two date cols and several other cols.

```
+-------+-----------+----------+----------+--
|     ID|      date1|  date2   | othercols|
|     1 | 2019-04-01|2019-05-01|      345 |
|     2 | 2019-05-01|2019-06-01|      334 |
|     3 | 2019-06-01|2019-05-01|      324 |
```

I want to union these two date columns into a new column such that the rows are duplicated for every entry.
I also want to use a condition of adding the date to a new columns such as date1 <= given_date & date2 <= given_date or so on.
The resultant dataframe should look like:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--
|     ID|     date1|     date2| all_dates| othercols|
|     1 |2019-04-01|2019-05-01|2019-04-01|   345    |
|     1 |2019-04-01|2019-05-01|2019-05-01|   345    |
|     2 |2019-05-01|2019-06-01|2019-05-01|   334    |
|     2 |2019-05-01|2019-06-01|2019-06-01|   334    |
|     3 |2019-06-01|2019-05-01|2019-06-01|   324    |
|     3 |2019-06-01|2019-05-01|2019-05-01|   324    |
```

Basically all dates for a particular id, keeping information of other columns intact.

From my [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=combine+two+columns+to+a+new+column+in+pyspark) of stack overflow, I could find answers on combining columns to a new column and creating an array or list in the new column. Any search on [union](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=union+of+two+columns+in+pyspark+dataframe), resulted in unions of different dataframes etc.

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column and explode it into new rows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("date_array", F.array(df.date1, df.date2)).withColumn("all_dates", F.explode("date_array"))
```